# THREEJS and polygon groups

Tags: three.js, mesh

I have a 3D model stored in OBJ file format. I can load the OBJ file using the OBJLoader just fine.

The model renders correctly and material applied correctly.

What is missing is the loading of polygon groups defined in the OBJ file to identify certain areas in the Model to be able to apply different materials over it.

When I look into the OBJLoader source, I found that it ignores the loading of the polygon groups segments.

How can I read the polygon groups using the OBJLoader and create additional child mesh objects to assign to the parent Model Object3D?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to solve this problem

[Download](http://www.blender.org/download) the open source 3D modeling application Blender and install it.
Open your OBJ files using Blender.
Export the OBJ model to another format, I used Collada format which works for me
Use the THREE.JS Collada loader
Collada loader will load the object model and its groups and materials successfully.

Hope this help you guys